# Merging Two Dataframes stacks rows instead of merging into one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm attempting to merge two dataframes using two columns as keys: "Date" and "Instrument"

Here is my code:

```
merge_df = pd.merge(df1 , df2,  how='outer', left_on=['Date','Instrument'], right_on = ['Date','Instrument'])
```

df1:
[image]

df2:
[image]

You'll notice that the row in each dataframe has the same instrument and date value: AEA000201011 & 2008-01-31.

The merged dataframe is stacking the two rows instead of combining them:

merged_df:
[image]

I have ensured that the dataframe key columns dtypes match:

df1:[image]

df2: [image]

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Man I wish I could use add comment section.

Even though you've probably already tried, have tried to use "left" or "right" instead of "outer"
Or for once check them like

```
df1["Instrument"].iloc[0] == df2["Instrument"].iloc[0]
```

Maybe they got some invisible chars in them. If it's like that you can try using strip() functions.
Nothing other than these comes to my mind.